# Is there more chance having collisions between GUID's or a SHA1 hashes of GUID's?

Tags: algorithm, guid, sha1, hash-collision

Is there more chance having collisions when betweens `GUID's` (128 bits) or SHA1 hashes of `GUID's` (160 bits) ? My opinion is there is less chance with a `GUID` (even if there is 32 bit less), because it has some special mechanisms to make sure it is (almost, because no guarantee) unique (ex : timestamp)

Note : i already know that a `GUID` is very unlikely to have a collision with another `GUID`, no more debate about this please.

Comment: hash collisions are unavoidable. all you can do is try to use a hash which has a key space large enough that collisions are unlikely to occur in your usage scenario.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's trivial: *if* two GUIDs are the same (that is, for each GUID collision), their hashes are also the same (we have a "collision" which is not a "SHA1 collision", but it's bad enough for our application). Plus there is a probability of a hash collision proper (same SHA1 for different GUIDs).

You can only add collisions if you hash your GUIDs.

Comment: Agree. It doesn't even matter how GUIDs are made, or how many bits in the SHA1 hash. Your last sentence says it all.

Comment: Do we know for sure if there is a non-zero probability of two distinct 128 bit GUIDs generating a SHA1 collision?  If so, do you know what that probability is?

Comment: @mbeckish - Per the birthday problem, there's roughly a >25% chance of getting a collision hashing all unique GUIDs into a hash space of 256 bits. Would be much higher chance with only 160 bits.

Comment: @hatchet - The birthday problem would only apply if 160 bit SHA1 hashes are randomly assigned to  inputs that are less than 160 bits, right?  Do we know if that is the case for SHA1?  It's certainly not true for all possible hashing functions.  For example, taking MOD 2^160 would not produce any collisions for inputs < 2^160.

Comment: @mbeckish - you're right...that's why I said "roughly". At best, hashing a GUID would have the same chance of collisions as just generating a GUID. But by hashing the GUID to a new value in a limited hash space, you can create an additional opportunity for collision, where the birthday problem will be an issue. But like you say, it may depend on how the hashing function hashes the Guid.

Comment: @hatchet - But the essence of this question is that the hash space (160 bits) is larger than the input space (128 bits), so collisions are not a foregone conclusion.  My modulo example provides a case where the birthday problem does not apply at all to the hash function.  Do we know if the birthday problem applies in particular to SHA1?

Comment: @mbeckish - Since one of the goals of a good hash function is to produce very different results given small changes in input, I'd say the birthday problem probably applies here. I don't _know_ that to be the case though.

Comment: @hatchet- I agree - it does seem likely.